# Get the value from $node inside two objects

Tags: 7

I have an array output like this from drupal, how do I access the value of [name] from 
field_episode_tags, I have this so far

```
print $node->field_episode_tags['und']['0']['taxonomy_term']->['name']
```

When I get up to 'taxonomy term' there is another object i tried using another -> poitner but that did not work.

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [vid] => 25
        [uid] => 1
        [title] => Is there any cosmos theory?
        [log] => 
        [status] => 1
        [comment] => 1
        [promote] => 0
        [sticky] => 0
        [nid] => 25
        [type] => tv_episode
        [language] => en
        [created] => 1380610491
        [changed] => 1381115053
        [tnid] => 0
        [translate] => 0
        [revision_timestamp] => 1381115053
        [revision_uid] => 1
        [body] => Array
            (
                [und] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text 
                                [summary] => 
                                [format] => filtered_html
                                [safe_value] => <p>summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text</p>

                                [safe_summary] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

        [field_video_category] => Array
            (
                [und] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [tid] => 25
                            )

                    )

            )

        [field_featured] => Array
            (
            )

        [field_kaltura_video] => Array
            (
            ) und 0 taxonomy term->name

        [field_episode_tags] => Array
            (
                [und] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [tid] => 95
                                [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [tid] => 95
                                        [vid] => 1
                                        [name] => zen
                                        [description] => 
                                        [format] => 
                                        [weight] => 0
                                        [vocabulary_machine_name] => tags


                       [rdf_mapping] => Array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way would be

```
print $node->field_episode_tags['und']['0']['taxonomy_term']->name
```

without the square brackets and quotes. Elements with in objects are accessed with

```
->objectname
```

and elements with in arrays are accessed by `['object']`